# Hide all (not)matching lines in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible to show/hide all matching lines in vi or Vim? Not highlight but just show only those lines.

For example I have a text with word the word `ERROR`. How do I make it show only lines containing `ERROR` and how to show only lines without `ERROR`?

Is there a solution *without deleting* all matching lines and then just undoing it?

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2280/12111

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Do you know about the `:global` command? Does this do what you want?

```
:g/ERROR
```

and for the opposite:

```
:g!/Error
```

or equivalently:

```
:v/Error
```

Comment: This is not very good.  Once you scroll to the bottom, then the command finishes and everything show up again.  It is not really hiding those contents.

Comment: @KanLi hit `g<` to see again, or `@:` if you havent run and commands.

Comment: you can delete :v/Error /d
to get back undo "u"

Comment: Is it possible to preserve syntax highlights from the original buffer in that "filtered window" after `:g/pattern/`?

Answer (score 55):

Another approach depending on your use case would be using **vimgrep** and its results in **quickfix**. You can do the following:

`:vimgrep pattern %` will search the current file and take you to the first search result. More importantly it also puts the results in the "quickfix list".

`:copen` will then open the quickfix list in a separate quickfix-window. So you will have a separate window with all lines from your last vimgrep. Inside the quickfix-window you can then hit Enter or double-click on a line to jump to the corresponding line in your original file.

`:colder` will let you go back to older quickfix lists (older vimgrep results). And `:cnewer` goes forward to newer search results.

Note that the quickfix list is also updated when running `:make` (which is why its called quickfix for fixing errors). Because of this there also is an alterative to the quickfix list called the "location list". To use it instead you use `:lvimgrep`, then use l-prefixed commands rather than c-prefixed commands - `:lopen`, `:lolder`, `:lnewer`.

There is, of course, a lot more you can do. See `:help quickfix` for more info.

PS, You said you didn't want an approach that deletes lines and then undoing them. But since you marked `g/ERROR`as the answer I thought I would point out a quick and dirty way is to do `g!/ERROR/d`. You can then easily undo it using `u`. Also FYI, you can do `:set hlsearch` to highlight patterns matched with `:g` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ":g!/ERROR/d" better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you do this with lines _not_ matching the pattern?

Answer (score 41):

You can use

```
:g/ERROR/
```

to print all the lines with ERROR

Also there is a Vim plugin which I saw many times but didn't use:
[foldsearch : fold away lines that don't match a given pattern](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2302)

Comment: +1 for the link to the foldsearch plugin. It's unobtrusive and can come in handy.

Answer (score 31):

The best way to do this is->

```
:vimgrep /something/g % | copen
```

This will open the list of matches for your keyword and also will show only the matched lines in quickfix window.

Replace % with path to file if not considering the current file.

Comment: Replace % with the file path if you are not considering the current file.

Comment: Can you do this with lines _not_ matching the pattern?

Answer (score 3):

`:vimgrep /something/g % | copen` works awesome. Also `:g/<pattern>/d` can be used to delete lines with the pattern

Comment: This is exactly another answer on this question.

Answer (score 3):

in case you happen to use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md) you could use:

- `:Lines` in all open files
- `:BLines` only in open buffer
- `:Rg [pattern]` using `ripgrep`

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean command in less vi vim 
    & /pattern/ 
which shows lines containing /pattern/ (like grep).

Answer (score 0):

Some hackish dirty way to do this:

```
:w (save)
ggdG (deletes everything)
:.!grep something % (replace current line with grep output)
```

Answer (score 0):

then you can just do

```
:g!/<pattern>/d
```