# Vim: Show all lines not matching a pattern

Tags: vim

I have a json document with the following data.

```
"tag": null
```

I would like to find all the tags that don't have null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide all (not)matching lines in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862966/hide-all-notmatching-lines-in-vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`:v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3av) command:

```
:v/"tag": null/
```

Alternatively, you can use a search with a negative look-ahead assertion (you can use `set hlsearch` to highlight the matches):

```
/"tag": \(null\)\@!
```

Comment: ...and if you want to "Show all lines not matching a pattern.", use [`:v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:v).