# find all word non matching pattern in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I've found the way to do this is using negative - lookahead and / or posistive lookbehind but I don't seem to find how to type it.

I'm trying to highlight all the lines where the word `length` is not present

I'm writing ( without success )  `/length\@!/`

What would be the correct way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide all (not)matching lines in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862966/hide-all-notmatching-lines-in-vim)

Comment: @jmort253 Not the same, I'm searching and want to highlight the non matching word. The referred answer hides the non matching lines and highlights the matching one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/^\(\(length\)\@!.\)*$/`

This is basically `^.*$` where `.` can't be followed by `length`.

In perl regex, it'd be `^((?!length).)*$`.

(Make sure you have `:set hlsearch` to actually highlight all the relevant lines).

Comment: Mmhh I'm missing something but don't know what : http://i.stack.imgur.com/jG8l0.png

Comment: Sorry, the regex has changed - I typo'd a backslash. It's been fixed now.

Comment: mmmhh almost.. now I neeed to type an empty space to avoid having the `length` word highlighted :-( http://i.stack.imgur.com/j493o.png

Comment: OK, adjusted regex one more time.